# Adding multiple files to androidManfist.xml

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a simple project that can switch between views. I have a `mainActvity.kt` file that connects to `main_actvity.xml` then I have a `profile.kt` file that connects to `fragment_profile.xml`. I need to add `profile.kt` to `androidManfist.xml` file anyone know how to do that? So when I press the `button` the `text` of a `textView` should turn to "`Hi how are you doing?"`. I have different files because when I try to find an element with id in `MainActvity.kt` it would give me the error null. conclusion the issue that I am facing is that android won't run a file that is connected to `fragment_profile.xml`. I have tried almost everything.

This is my `AndroidManfist.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lecture">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Profile"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and here is my `profile.kt` file

```
    package com.example.lecture

    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.TextView
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

    class Profile(): AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_notifications)
            val update = findViewById<Button>(R.id.updateButton)
            update.setOnClickListener{ toaster() }

        }

        private fun toaster() {
            val password = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.passwordAddressText)
            password.text = "Hi how are you doing?"
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I have a profile.kt file that connects to fragment_profile.xml." – If `profile` is indeed a `Fragment`, you don't list it in the manifest. Only `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, and `ContentProvider` subclasses are listed in the manifest.

Comment: It still does not work I removed the command that makes the file a fragment and ran it. It still didn't work.

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to be able to determine what exactly you're trying to do, or why it's not working. Please [edit] your question to better explain the issue, and to include any relevant code and XML.

Comment: Okay, I added the code and added more about my problem. Is this enough or would you like me to add more?

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your androidManfist.xml

```
<activity android:name=".profile" />
```

Comment: It did't work for me. I have code that when a button is pressed it should change the text and I know It works because I changed the launch file to that file and it worked.